# Zooming in map makes deleted layer reappear in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geolocation, layer

I am developing an application that uses leaflet routing machine. When clicking the option to create a layer, the route is created on the map as shown below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KW9Id.jpg

Afterwards, I click on the other option to choose another layer. I have a function which deletes the previous layer before creating this one. The result is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/25vXD.jpg

While being on the 2nd option, if I zoom on the map the first layer which was previously deleted reappears, without the waypoints though, as shown below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVHf.jpg

I do not know why this is the case

Code used to delete layers ( using a bool as a flag for first time execution )

```
var flag = false
if (flag) {
        bootleaf.map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            if (!!layer.toGeoJSON) {
              bootleaf.map.removeLayer(layer);
            }
        });
    }

drawLiedman(choice.value);
flag = true
```

Code used to draw the layer-path:

```
function drawLiedman(userId) {

    let demoArray = []
    var coords = []
    //var counter = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        if (config.drivers[i].name == userId) {
            driverUrl = config.drivers[i].coords;
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(driverUrl)

    $.getJSON(driverUrl)
    .done(function(response) {
        demoArray = (response);

        demoArray.forEach( (element,index) => { 
            const LatLng = element.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(", ")
            const Lat = parseFloat(LatLng[0]);
            const Lng = parseFloat(LatLng[1]);

            coords[index] = L.latLng(Lat,Lng); 
            
        });

        L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: coords,
            addWaypoints: false,
            routeWhileDragging: false,
            profile: 'route/v1/driving',
            createMarker: function(i, wp) { 
                
                    return L.marker(wp.latLng, {
                    
                    draggable: false,
                    
                    icon: L.icon.glyph({
                        
                        glyph: i
                        
                        })
                    
                    }).addTo(bootleaf.map);
                },
            serviceUrl: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
            lineOptions: {
                     styles: [{color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 2}]
            },
            show:false
        }).addTo(bootleaf.map);

    })
        
}
```

I basically have a JSON file with 19 drivers and some urls. I then grab the data dynamically from them and process them. Afterwards, I draw the layers. I do not understand where that error occurs, as after deleting the layer it's supposed to not reappear again after zooming. Any feedback is welcome, I can also provide more info on this if needed.

EDIT- After further searching, it appears that this could be an issue caused by the fact that the layer is stored somewhere in the routing machine. I am using Liedman's Leaflet Routing Machine, and I used css to hide the instructions. However once I made them appear again, hovering over the instructions recreated the old layer over the new one. Any suggestions on how to completely erase the layer and its instructions?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yp0Y4.jpg